# Android toString changes ArrayList probability

Tags: android, arraylist, probability, tostring

I'm creating an android dice roll calculator for risk but the probabilities seem to be broken and dynamic. I've also written a python program, which I've checked mathematically for accuracy, to match the probabilities with. The "String troubleshoot" variable assignment (which is not called anywhere else, it simply is executed) is necessary for the app to match probabilities for dice rolls with more than one dice on both sides. The app will not match probabilities if any side uses one dice, and without the troubleshoot assignment it never matches. Below is the function where editing changes the outcome.

Why would .toString on an ArrayList change the outcome, and any ideas on making the one dice rolls match? I think the two dice roll successful matching has something to do with the .toString on either a single object or a multi-item array.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> roll_dice(int numOfDice) {
    ArrayList<Integer> diceList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int count = 0; count < numOfDice; count++){
        int diceValue = random.nextInt(6)+1;
        diceList.add(diceValue);
    }               
    // below line changes probabilities to match python except for any battles with one dice on a side.
    String troubleshootList = diceList.toString(); 

    Collections.sort(diceList); 
    Collections.reverse(diceList);      
    return diceList;
}
```

Comment: how does this troubleshootList variable change the probability?? I cant see anything releated to probability except random.nextInt

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. (1) Even if `toString()` somehow affected random, you're executing it _after_ filling `diceList`, so it cannot be affecting you in this case. (2) What do you mean by _"making the one dice rolls match"_?.

Comment: Illegal Argument, that's actually one of the two questions I'm asking, since I know it shouldn't. While experimenting I also found adding in similar lines after the .reverse and after the .add will affect the outcome as well.
Matiash, it is affecting me somehow, it just seems inexplicable, and my making the dice rolls match I mean getting the same probability numbers on my android app as I get from my python code, which does give the correct probability.

Answer (score 0):

Just change a little in your programming way..

```
String troubleshootList = "";

for (String s : diceList )
{
  troubleshootList += s + "\t";
}
```

It should be alright..